# Retrieving Multiple Distinct Attribute in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I m using mongodb to generate a report .The report is having multiple dynamic drop down.SO i need to write a rest api in java for this purpose.
My mongodb collection is of type

```
    ` {_id:{"name" :"abc","salary" : "100", "year" :"1990"}, .. .. 
         . . .. . . .. }
```

I need to retrieve distinct name ,salary and year from it. Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Your data is a bit confusing to understand. can you please post either your schema or more properly formatted data for us to give some solution?

Comment: Something like `db.collection.aggregate({$group:{_id:{name:"$name", salary:"$salary", year:"$year"}}})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
    $group: {_id: null, name: {$addToSet: "$name"}, salary: {$addToSet: "$salary"}, year: {$addToSet: "$year"}}
}])
```

Comment: Thanks Let me check and i will get back to u .This look fine for what i was looking @Shantanu Madane